# How to add a mixin to a chunk of CSS?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, sass, media-queries, mixins, respond.js

I made a huge mistake and I'm looking for some help.

After building a site with CSS, mobile-first responsive, with respond.js as a polyfill, after I tested it in IE compatibility mode during developing I realized at the end that there's a big conflict between respond.js and the javascript used by the CMS and the Internet Explorer 8 blocks everything from rendering.
I decided to drop the polyfill entirely and go the SASS way with it, using a MQ mixin.

Right now the problem is that IE8 is seeing the mobile version of the website
(sorry I can't give you a link to it)

I have included conditionizr for < ie9 and I have used css2sass to get my CSS nested a little.

I found a great MQ mixin by [Stuart Robson](https://twitter.com/StuRobson) ([here](http://alwaystwisted.com/post.php?s=2013-04-01-my-media-query-mixin)) ** that I have not yet started to add it, the question is, do I have any other option than to go and edit everywhere I used mq in the code?

The mixin I think I have to use looks like this ** (adapted it a little to make a better use of it for my problem):

```
@mixin mq($point, $IE9: true, $query1: min, $query2: width) {
@if $IE9 == true{
    @media screen and (#{$query1}-#{$query2}: $point +px) {
        @content;
    }
    .lt-ie9 & {
        @content;
    }
}

@else {
    @media screen and (#{$query1}-#{$query2}: $point +px) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

}

I'm not going to debug the JavaScript code to make the polyfill work. I have tried several other scripts (including css3-mediaqueries) but I dropped the idea of help from javascript and I want to go the SASS way.

Given that there's a chunk of almost 6k lines of SASS code, is there any SASS way to help me with adding the mixin somehow so that I end up getting something like this?

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
 body {
  margin: 0;
}
}
.lt-ie9 body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

I learned my lesson, started using BrowserStack and I will only go with that mixin from now on. There's still the problem at hand that has to be fixed..
Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  The mixin you have should generate the output you're looking for.

Comment: Please use http://codepen.io to share code that behaves problematically. Don't copy the whole project, reduce it as much as possible, keeping only the problematic part.

Comment: @cimmanon It's not added; that's what I am trying to figure out. Going through the whole CSS and edit every class that uses MQ is my only option at this point? I didn't know sass 2 weeks ago when I made the CSS.

Comment: @lolmaus That is a mixin and the CSS output if it would be used. The whole project is 5000 CSS lines that were converted to SASS. Sorry if the description is too long. Got a comment on it though? I got the codepen tip, thank you

Comment: Did you wrap the whole CSS into this mixin? It is supposed to be used only for small bits that IE8 can't cope with.

Comment: @lolmaus no, I have not yet used the mixin, sorry it wasn't clear at first. The thing is do I go and edit all the mq manually or is there a smarter way to get the desired result? Thanks!

Comment: You declare the mixin once and then apply it as many times as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will edit all the MQs to use the new mixin and I also have to learn more SASS and stop asking silly questions about it! :)
Thanks everyone!